Probability of choosing the same number of balls of each colour from a pot containing $m$ different colours
I recently answered this question, where $2k$ balls are drawn, one at a time and with replacement, from a pot with $n$ black balls and $n$ white balls.
Because it is with replacement, there are always the same number of each ball when drawing, so there's a 50/50 chance each time of drawing a specific colour. I used this fact to show that the probability of drawing the same number of each colour is independent of $n$.
I'm now interested in what happens when there are $m$ different colours in the pot and $mk$ balls are drawn. The total number of cases is $m^{mk}$, but I'm not 100% sure how many favourable cases there are.
My intuition is: first choose $k$ of the balls to be one colour (so $\binom{mk}{k}$ cases), then choose $k$ of the remaining $(m-1)k$ balls to be another colour (so $\binom{(m-1)k}{k}$ cases) and so on, until you choose $k$ of the remaining $2k$ balls to be the penultimate colour, leaving the final $k$ balls fixed.
This would be $$\prod_{i=0}^{m-2}\binom{(m-i)k}{k}.$$ Is this correct?
Also, note that $$\require{cancel}\prod_{i=0}^{m-2}\binom{(m-i)k}{k} = \frac{(mk)!}{k!\cancel{([m-1]k)!}}\frac{\cancel{([m-1]k)!}}{k!\cancel{([m-2]k)!}}\dots\frac{\cancel{(3k)!}}{k!\cancel{(2k)!}}\frac{\cancel{(2k)!}}{(k!)^2} = \frac{(mk)!}{(k!)^m},$$ which is a super simple expression (indeed is the same as I found in the other question, with $m=2$. Therefore, is there a simpler argument to the one I made above?

Easiest to adapt this answer to a multinomial distribution.  The number of ways of selecting the balls is $$\frac{(mk)!}{(k!)^m},$$ so the problem reduces to computing the probability that the 1st $~k~$ balls are all Color-1, the 2nd $~k~$ balls are all Color-2, ..., the last $~k~$ balls are all Color-m.

Re my last comment, in effect, your analysis is a re-invention of the wheel of the multinomial theorem.

This is just the multinomial distribution.
Denote $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m)$ as the number of balls drawn in each color, where $mk$ balls are drawn in total with replacement.
Then
$$ (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m) \sim \mathrm{Multinomial}
\left(mk; \frac {1} {m}, \frac {1} {m}, \ldots, \frac {1} {m} \right)$$
The joint pmf is given by
$$ \Pr\{X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, \ldots, X_m = x_m\} 
= \frac {(mk)!} {\prod_{i=1}^m x_i! } \prod_{i=1}^m \frac {1} {m^{x_i}}
= \frac {(mk)!} {\prod_{i=1}^m x_i! } \frac {1} {m^{mk}}
$$
where $x_i \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, mk\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i = mk$
The coefficient
$$ \frac {(mk)!} {\prod_{i=1}^m x_i!} $$
is the multinomial coefficient which you may think as the number of favourable outcomes, and in your case $x_i = k$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, m$
You may find different sources explaining about the multinomial coefficients.
A simple argument may follow like this: $(mk)!$ gives the number of permutations for distinct $mk$ objects. Now the $mk$ objects are partitioned into $m$ groups and the objects in each group are indistinguishable, so we need to divide by the redundant permutations $x_i!$, where $x_i$ is the size of each group.

Thanks! And you've answered the natural extension too, which is when there are $n_i$ copies of colour $i$ in the pot - so each $1/m$ would just be replaced by $n_i/n$, right?

Yes correct. The probability of each type (color) can be arbitrary probabilities $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m$, as long as $\sum_{i=1}^m p_i = 1$.
